# "Error updating Google" message when trying to enable Google Sign-In for Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I'm trying to enable the Google Sign-In provider in Firebase Authentication, but it's failing to be enabled when I click Save as I'm getting a "Error updating Google" message.

[image]

I have added my SHA1 fingerprint to my Firebase project and I tried enabling the provider in incognito mode, but it still fails. I also checked the Menu -> More tools -> Developer tools for errors, but I don't see any. How do I fix this?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen As stated in my post, when I check the developer console by clicking Menu -> More tools -> Developer tools, there are no relevant error messages. This was in my Chrome browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to recreate the Firebase and Google Cloud projects.

After deleting everything, first create a Firebase project. Then, the Google Cloud project will be created automatically. There is no need to create a separate Google Cloud project.
After this, don't forget to delete and create new SHA-1 and web_client_id keys:

- delete the debug.keystore.
- run ./gradlew signingreport from the app's directory to make sure there are no keys remaining.
- build the app in Android Studio - it will generate new keys automatically during new build.
- run ./gradlew signingreport from the app's directory to make sure that new keys are there.

You may also refer to this [documentation](http://www.churyumov.com/2021/06/how-to-implement-sign-in-via-google.html).

Comment: I have posted an answer. Can you check if that helps?